# CSS styles defined in <head> not being applied?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on this page: http://sydneypadua.com/2dgoggles/

And I'm trying to redefine the width of `content-sidebar-wrap`, in order to stop the left-hand sidebar being pushed down to the bottom of the page.

Look in View Source and you will see where I have added the new style:

```
.double-sidebar #content-sidebar-wrap {
    width: 795px ! important;
}
```

But use Chrome Developer Tools to inspect the styles being applied to the `content-sidebar-wrap` div, and you will only see:

```
width: 780px;
    .double-sidebar #content-sidebar-wrap - 780px style.css:596
    [with strikethrough] #content-sidebar-wrap - 960px style.css:591
```

Why isn't the style I have defined in the head of the page being picked up?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you remove the space from "! important"?

Comment: @Gary have just tried that, and it doesn't seem to, no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to [validate the css of your page](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?profile=css21&warning=0&uri=http://sydneypadua.com/2dgoggles/) and these errors came out into the page:

```
32  .double-sidebar #content-sidebar-wrap   Lexical error at line 33, column 1.  
     Encountered: "\ufffd" (65533), after : "" � � width: 795px !important;
33  .double-sidebar #content-sidebar-wrap   Parse Error }
45   *  Parse Error */ #content .post 
    { padding-left: 5px ! important; padding-right: 5px ! important; }
```

Probably you inserted an unrecognized character (due to a copy and paste, maybe?) resulting in a parser error, so try to rewrite the entire rule.

Comment: I just found that as well.  i just deleted it and retyped it in. and it worked.

Comment: That's amazing! Thank you so much. Next time I will know to try validation when all else fails.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the style tag doesn't like the id remove it and it should work fine.

```
<style     type="text/css">    
//no id ^
//Other rules...

/* Fix for sidebar widths. */

.double-sidebar #content-sidebar-wrap {
    width: 795px !important;
}

//other rules...

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I see in FF when I browse your css http://sydneypadua.com/2dgoggles/ :

```
.double-sidebar #content-sidebar-wrap {
}
```

I'm sure "!important" shouldn't have a space.

Comment: No, it's not the whitespace; the whitespace doesn't matter. Even the code examples in the [W3C's own specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html#important-rules) have a space there!

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
#content-sidebar-wrap {
    width: 795px !important;
}
```

**.double-sidebar** is not needed because **#content-sidebar-wrap** determines div unambiguously.

Comment: True, it isn't needed. But that is not the cause of the problem. It is not an error. Besides, there may be circumstances where `.classname #idname` is more specific than `#idname alone`, for instance when you have a css file applying to more than one HTML file, and each HTML file contains the same id, but you only want to style one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `*/` at the end of the `.double-sidebar #sidebar-1-wrap` class, because that could be breaking your css, and rewrite the css rule `.double-sidebar #content-sidebar-wrap`.

Also, just as a reminder, if you are styling ids, you don't need to specify a class before them, the selectors are read from right to left so with the id alone is enough